# How to set the date format of a ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker?

Tags: zend-framework, jquery-ui, zend-form, zendx

I am trying to set the date format of the date picker element, but I can't get it to work. How do you set the date format of a `ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker` element?

### Solution:

Strange...I tried my original code sample again, and it worked.

```
$element = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('date', array(
    'jQueryParams' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd' //displays: 2010-01-26
    ),
));
```

Comment: you have small mistake in code `,` must be `=>`

Comment: ah! you are right. must have been it all along!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$element = new ZendX_JQuery_Form_Element_DatePicker('date', array(
    'jQueryParams' => array(
        'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-D'
    ),
));
```

Comment: hmm strange...I tried my original code sample again and it worked just fine. Also, your format ('yy-mm-D') results in '2009-21-Mon'.